# How to make amp-accordion with a multiple child (some child will have grand child)

Tags: html, amp-html

I am trying to implement a amp-accordion on my amp-page. According to requirement some item of my accordion will have grand-child.

Did anyone have did anything like this. I am trying to add some item in last example on this page https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-accordion/#nested-accordions on playground. 
It always end up invalid code. How I can make a accordion which will work with child and grand-child (2child of child)

Code for 1-level-nesting

```
<amp-accordion disable-session-states>
  <section>
    <h4>Section 1</h4>
    <p>Bunch of content.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h4>Section 2</h4>
    <amp-accordion class="nested-accordion">
      <section>
        <h4>Nested Section 2.1</h4>
        <p>Bunch of content.</p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h4>Nested Section 2.2</h4>
        <p>Bunch of more content.</p>
      </section>
    </amp-accordion>
  </section>
</amp-accordion>
```

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 1):

What kind of error do you get?

The reason might be that there are more than 2 children, inside *section* tag.
Each section **must** have exactly two children. As a workaround, you can wrap the other elements inside a *div* so that you can have only 2 children.

[image]

Later edit: 
You can have A (in our case *h4*) and B (in our case *div*) which includes C, D, E, ...

```
<amp-accordion disable-session-states>
    <section>
        <h4>Section</h4>
        <div class="wrap-list">
            <ul>
              <li>1</li>
              <li>2</li>
              <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </section>
 </amp-accordion>
```

Comment: @Zedka, This is the exact issue I am facing, I have a A B C which can have their child.This thing doesn't fulfill the requirement.

Comment: Try to wrap the additional children inside another element as in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this sequence(if I got your issue correct)

```
<amp-accordion>
  <section>
    <h4>Your title here</h4>
    <div>
      <amp-accordion> <!-- your first level child here -->
        <section>
          <h4>Your first level child title here</h4>
          <div>
            <amp-accordion> <!-- your second level child here -->
              <section>
                <h4>your second child title-1 here</h4>
                <div>...</div>
              </section>
              <section>
                <h4>your second child title-2 here</h4>
                <div>...</div>
              </section>
            </amp-accordion>
          </div>
        </section>
      </amp-accordion>
    </div>
  </section>
</amp-accordion>
```

and so on and so forth...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just using checkbox for toggle show/hide?

Comment: It's navigation bar, Check TheGuardian, My implementation is quite similar to that one but in implementation I have child of childs. Using Checkbox will be weird in this case.

Comment: Check my ex: https://rawgit.com/buihoanghai/html-only/master/accordion.html

Comment: Level 0 using radio, level 1 using checkbox

Comment: I am going to holiday, I will come next week, If I get internet connectivity, I will clearly try your example. Thanks for helping me, :)